# How to check the output gradient by each layer in pytorch in my code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, gradient

I am working on the pytorch to learn.

And  There is a question how to check the output gradient by each layer in my code.

My code is below

```
#import the nescessary libs
import numpy as np
import torch
import time

# Loading the Fashion-MNIST dataset
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

# Get GPU Device

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")


# Define a transform to normalize the data
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
                                                                   ])
# Download and load the training data
trainset = datasets.FashionMNIST('MNIST_data/', download = True, train = True, transform = transform)
testset = datasets.FashionMNIST('MNIST_data/', download = True, train = False, transform = transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size = 32, shuffle = True, num_workers=4)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size = 32, shuffle = True, num_workers=4)

# Examine a sample
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()

# Define the network architecture
from torch import nn, optim
import torch.nn.functional as F

model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(784, 128),
                      nn.ReLU(),
                      nn.Linear(128, 10),
                      nn.LogSoftmax(dim = 1)
                     )
model.to(device)

# Define the loss
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Define the optimizer
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 0.001)

# Define the epochs
epochs = 5

train_losses, test_losses = [], []

# start = time.time()
for e in range(epochs):
    running_loss = 0
    
    for images, labels in trainloader:
    # Flatten Fashion-MNIST images into a 784 long vector
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        images = images.view(images.shape[0], -1)
        

    # Training pass
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    
        output = model.forward(images)
        loss = criterion(output, labels)
        
        loss.backward()
        
#         print(loss.grad)
        
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
    
    else:
        print(model[0].grad)
```

If I print model[0].grad after back-propagation, Is it going to be the output gradient by each layer for every epoches?

Or, If I want to know the output gradient by each layer, where and what am I should print?

Thank you!!

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, this is a good question if you need to know the inner computation within your model. Let me explain to you!

So firstly when you print the `model` variable you'll get this output:

```
Sequential(
  (0): Linear(in_features=784, out_features=128, bias=True)
  (1): ReLU()
  (2): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=10, bias=True)
  (3): LogSoftmax(dim=1)
)
```

And if you choose `model[0]`, that means you have selected the first layer of the model. that is `Linear(in_features=784, out_features=128, bias=True)`. If you will look at the documentation of `torch.nn.Linear` [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html), you will find that there are two variables to this class that you can access. One is **Linear.weight** and the other is **Linear.bias** which will give you the weights and biases of that corresponding layer respectively.

Remember you cannot use `model.weight` to look at the weights of the model as your linear layers are kept inside a container called `nn.Sequential` which doesn't has a `weight` attribute.

So coming back to looking at weights and biases, you can access them per layer. So `model[0].weight` and `model[0].bias` are the weights and biases of the first layer. And similarly to access the gradients of the first layer `model[0].weight.grad` and `model[0].bias.grad` will be the gradients.

Comment: This is a perfect answer that I want to know!! Awesome, thanks a lot, and what if I would love to know the "output" gradient for each layer?

Comment: If you mean gradient of each perceptron of each layer then `model[0].weight.grad` will show you exactly that (for 1st layer). And be sure to mark this answer as accepted if you like it.

Comment: What you mention is parameter gradient I think(taking `y = wx + b` parameter gradient is `w` and `b` here)? Does the output gradient refer to the gradient of `x`?

Comment: If you have `y=ln(x)` (or any other function per se) then the output gradient of y also changes with the value of x.. don't you think?

Comment: Does these greadients represent the value of last forward calculating? Can we get the gradients of each epoch?